# merging dataframes based on common rows in R

Tags: r, merge

I know that similar questions have been asked here, but I have two data frames of gene expression and there are some non-overlapping genes between the two datasets. I want to merge the two data frames based on common rows.
My data frames look like this:

```
 > print(fibro1[c(1:12),])
          C12    C24    C48    C72    T12    T24    T48    T72
Gnai3  3510.4 2319.1  974.8 2198.7 1936.2  829.9  807.3 1882.1
Cdc45    41.0   22.5   16.1   33.4   44.9    0.0    6.7   32.6
H19       0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   10.2
Scml2    29.8   43.8   25.0   10.8   79.5    0.0   26.2   46.0
Apoh     35.4    0.0    0.0    0.0   16.6   16.1    0.0    2.8
Narf    231.8  190.5  122.3  181.0  122.0   60.4   54.0  118.8
Cav2    196.9   53.7   36.4  130.9   80.9    6.7   17.9   79.0
Klf6  10478.8 5471.5 3337.1 5059.1 7987.7 2522.5 4117.2 5298.4
Scmh1  4235.9 1464.8  872.0 2254.5 2307.7  799.7  869.1 1959.1
Cox5a   142.4   68.0   97.0  112.8  251.8   23.0  163.9   71.3
Tbx2      5.8    9.5    4.5    5.6   13.4    0.0    8.5    9.6
Ngfr     58.1   60.6   50.7   32.1   46.1   57.7    0.0   10.7
> print(fibro2[c(1:12),])
         C12   C24    C48    C72    T12   T24    T48    T72
Gnai3 1171.0 446.0  278.5  876.2  876.2  45.0  582.3 1040.0
Cdc45   47.8   9.0   19.1   41.0   22.6   0.0   38.5   78.5
H19     77.0  52.2   33.4   36.7  177.9  34.7  402.1  458.6
Scml2    2.3   0.0   10.1    3.0   12.8   0.0    0.0    9.2
Narf    43.0   5.4    4.7   27.9   35.8   2.9   23.8  135.6
Cav2    54.6  23.3    5.3   10.7   64.0   0.0   30.1   40.4
Klf6  2498.4 730.7 1454.1 1033.0 2616.9 421.4 2389.6 2950.4
Scmh1  591.7 129.4  260.5  273.5  457.1  29.2  303.5  534.3
Cox5a   70.9  21.9   39.7   51.0  225.5  25.9  321.2   98.9
Tbx2     6.1   0.0    0.0   10.7    3.5   0.0    7.1   11.0
Tbx4     5.7   0.0    0.0    0.0    5.7   0.0    3.4    9.8
Ngfr    14.2   8.8   21.5   33.8    9.2  18.9   22.5   40.6
```

I have tried merge(), inner_join(), semi_join(), intersect(). Do you have any suggestions? I want my final data frame to have  16 columns of the intersecting rows.
Other similar questions have the row names in the same order, so the functions that are used can compare one on one, but in this example the row names are not in the same order and there are some non-overlapping ones.

Comment: `merge(fibro1, fibro2,  by = "row.names")` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `merge` on the row names as a separate column, then putting row names back in place.

```
merge(cbind(row = rownames(fibro1), fibro1), 
      cbind(row = rownames(fibro2), fibro2), by="row", all=T) |> 
  (\(x){rownames(x) <- x$row; x[,-1]})()
```

output

```
        C12.x  C24.x  C48.x  C72.x  T12.x  T24.x  T48.x  T72.x  C12.y C24.y
Apoh     35.4    0.0    0.0    0.0   16.6   16.1    0.0    2.8     NA    NA
Cav2    196.9   53.7   36.4  130.9   80.9    6.7   17.9   79.0   54.6  23.3
Cdc45    41.0   22.5   16.1   33.4   44.9    0.0    6.7   32.6   47.8   9.0
Cox5a   142.4   68.0   97.0  112.8  251.8   23.0  163.9   71.3   70.9  21.9
Gnai3  3510.4 2319.1  974.8 2198.7 1936.2  829.9  807.3 1882.1 1171.0 446.0
H19       0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   10.2   77.0  52.2
Klf6  10478.8 5471.5 3337.1 5059.1 7987.7 2522.5 4117.2 5298.4 2498.4 730.7
Narf    231.8  190.5  122.3  181.0  122.0   60.4   54.0  118.8   43.0   5.4
Ngfr     58.1   60.6   50.7   32.1   46.1   57.7    0.0   10.7   14.2   8.8
Scmh1  4235.9 1464.8  872.0 2254.5 2307.7  799.7  869.1 1959.1  591.7 129.4
Scml2    29.8   43.8   25.0   10.8   79.5    0.0   26.2   46.0    2.3   0.0
Tbx2      5.8    9.5    4.5    5.6   13.4    0.0    8.5    9.6    6.1   0.0
Tbx4       NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA    5.7   0.0
       C48.y  C72.y  T12.y T24.y  T48.y  T72.y
Apoh      NA     NA     NA    NA     NA     NA
Cav2     5.3   10.7   64.0   0.0   30.1   40.4
Cdc45   19.1   41.0   22.6   0.0   38.5   78.5
Cox5a   39.7   51.0  225.5  25.9  321.2   98.9
Gnai3  278.5  876.2  876.2  45.0  582.3 1040.0
H19     33.4   36.7  177.9  34.7  402.1  458.6
Klf6  1454.1 1033.0 2616.9 421.4 2389.6 2950.4
Narf     4.7   27.9   35.8   2.9   23.8  135.6
Ngfr    21.5   33.8    9.2  18.9   22.5   40.6
Scmh1  260.5  273.5  457.1  29.2  303.5  534.3
Scml2   10.1    3.0   12.8   0.0    0.0    9.2
Tbx2     0.0   10.7    3.5   0.0    7.1   11.0
Tbx4     0.0    0.0    5.7   0.0    3.4    9.8
```